# How to set Action Listener to 3 buttons

Tags: java, swing, listener, actionlistener, action-interface

I'm trying to make a stopwatch with three buttons, "Start", "Pause", and "Stop".  My instructor only taught us how to set Action Listeners to two buttons.  How do I set up Action Listeners to three buttons?  Here is my coding so far

```
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");

startButton.addActionListener(this);
stopButton.addActionListener(this);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (actionEvent.getActionCommand().equals("Start")){
        start = aCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        aJLabel.setText("Stopwatch is running...");
    } else {
        aJLabel.setText("Elapsed time is: " + 
                (double) (aCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - start) / 1000 );

    }
}
```

I haven't made any Action Listeners for my "Pause" feature yet because I don't know how to pause the timer anyway.  But I wanted to link the action to the button before I figured out how to pause.

Comment: Why would `pauseButton.addActoinListener(this)` not work?  Why would you not be able to add another `else if` statement to you code to test for it...?

Comment: Sorry what I had up originally did not work.  The "e.getSource()==startButton)" did not work because startButton was not a variable.  Not sure how to get that feature to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `if-then-else if-then` statement.

Basically, add the `ActionListener` to all three buttons as you have been doing...

```
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");

startButton.addActionListener(this);
stopButton.addActionListener(this);
pauseButton.addActionListener(this);
```

Then supply a `if-else-if` series of conditions to test for each possible occurrence (you are expecting)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (e.getSource() == startButton){
        start = aCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        aJLabel.setText("Stopwatch is running...");
    } else if (e.getSource() == stopButton) {
        aJLabel.setText("Elapsed time is: " + 
                (double) (aCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - start) / 1000 );
    } else if (e.getSource() == pauseButton) {
        // Do pause stuff
    }
}
```

Take a closer look at [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) for more details

Instead of trying to use the reference to the buttons, you might consider using the `actionCommand` property of the `AcionEvent` instead, this means you won't need to be able to reference the original buttons...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if ("Start".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
        start = aCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        aJLabel.setText("Stopwatch is running...");
    } else if ("Stop".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        aJLabel.setText("Elapsed time is: " + 
                (double) (aCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - start) / 1000 );
    } else if ("Pause".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        // Do pause stuff
    }
}
```

It also means that you could re-use the `ActionListener` for things like `JMenuItem`s, so long as they had the same `actionCommand`...

Now, having said that, I would encourage you not to follow this paradigm.  Normally, I would encourage you to use the `Action`s API, but that might be a little too advanced for where you're up to right now, instead, I would encourage you to take advantage of [Java's anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) support, for example....

```
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        start = aCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        aJLabel.setText("Stopwatch is running...");
    }
});
stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        aJLabel.setText("Elapsed time is: "
                + (double) (aCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - start) / 1000);
    }
});
pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Do pause stuff
    }
});
```

This isolates the responsibility for each button to a single `ActionListener`, which makes it easier to see what's going on and when required, modify them without fear or affecting the others.

It also does away with the need to maintain a reference to the button (as it can be obtained via the `ActionEvent` `getSource` property)

Comment: Thank you for giving me so many options and thoroughly explaining each one. I don't think I knew about if-else-if conditions.  This really helped!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to implement ActionListener you can add anonymous listener to your button like this:

```
 JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
 JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
 JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
 startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //start action logic here
        }
    });
 stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //stop action logic here
        }
    });
 pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //action logic here
        }
    });
```

And this solution have to work :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to add is this  after the buttons creation.

```
startButton.setActionCommand("Start");
stopButton.setActionCommand("Stop");
pauseButton.setActionCommand("Pause");
```

and in actionPerformed method use this.

```
switch(actionEvent.getActionCommand())
{
// cases
}
```